# Mysql8 Unable to order the result of WITH RECURSIVE query

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, mysql-8.0

I am using the `WITH RECURSIVE` query to generate a hierarchy of users. The data and the query used is shared in https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oTbCcMQb5a4B6V96DAYJHG/0 . The query is returning the results correctly, but the order of the data is different from what i need.

I have tweaked the query a few times, but unable to achieve the required result.
**Actual Result of the query**

```
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| id  | title  | parent_id  | sort_order |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1  | null   | null       |          0 |
|  2  | A      | 1          |          1 |
|  3  | B      | 1          |          2 |
|  4  | AA     | 2          |          1 |
|  5  | AB     | 2          |          2 |
| 13  | BA     | 3          |          1 |
| 17  | BC     | 3          |          2 |
|  6  | AAA    | 4          |          1 |
|  7  | AAB    | 4          |          2 |
|  8  | AAC    | 4          |          3 |
|  9  | ABA    | 5          |          1 |
| 10  | ABB    | 5          |          2 |
| 11  | ABC    | 5          |          3 |
| 12  | ABD    | 5          |          4 |
| 16  | BAA    | 13         |          1 |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
```

**Result I am trying to achieve**

```
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
| id  | title  | parent_id  | sort_order |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
|  1  | null   | null       |          0 |
|  2  | A      | 1          |          1 |
|  4  | AA     | 2          |          1 |
|  6  | AAA    | 4          |          1 |
|  7  | AAB    | 4          |          2 |
|  8  | AAC    | 4          |          3 |
|  5  | AB     | 2          |          2 |
|  9  | ABA    | 5          |          1 |
| 10  | ABB    | 5          |          2 |
| 11  | ABC    | 5          |          3 |
| 12  | ABD    | 5          |          4 |
|  3  | B      | 1          |          2 |
| 13  | BA     | 3          |          1 |
| 16  | BAA    | 13         |          1 |
| 17  | BC     | 3          |          2 |
+-----+--------+------------+------------+
```

In my query the `WITH RECURSIVE` will take all nodes of level 1, then it will take all level2 and continues..

But the result I am trying to achieve is take first node of first level, complete the hierarchy, then take second element of the first level and recurse through rest.

Is is possible to get this result using `WITH RECURSIVE`

> The data in the title is sample data, so that it is easy to understand the hierarchy.

Comment: Create path and use it for sorting: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yCF8Lww8), article: [link](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-1-recursive-common-table-expressions-in-mysql-ctes-part-four-depth-first-or-breadth-first-traversal-transitive-closure-cycle-avoidance/).

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it... such as 
Select * from (your existing recursive query) as AfterRecursiveResult order by AfterRecursiveResult.ColumnA, AfterRecursiveResult.ColumnX, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Store the nodes in a temporary table based on their level and sort order, and then select the nodes from that table in the desired order.

You can try this query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    title,
    parent_id,
    sort_order,
    0 AS level
  FROM
    test
  WHERE
    parent_id IS NULL

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    t.id,
    t.title,
    t.parent_id,
    t.sort_order,
    cte.level + 1 AS level
  FROM
    test t
    JOIN cte ON t.parent_id = cte.id
)
SELECT
  cte.id,
  cte.title,
  cte.parent_id,
  cte.sort_order
FROM
  cte
ORDER BY
  cte.level,
  cte.sort_order;
```

There is `level` column to keep track of the hierarchy level of each node. Initial level for the root node is set to 0. Order the final result by level and sort_order, ensuring that nodes within each level are ordered correctly.